# How to print a message in error handling with try, catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple example:

```
var str = '{ "test"  : 1, }'

try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

result:

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token }]

How to print all error info ?

Expected result:

```
undefined:1
{ "test"  : 1, }
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Comment: There is no information in the error object about what character caused the error, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This will help:

```
var x = { asd: "asd", };

try {
    JSON.parse(x);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("Error", e.stack);
    console.log("Error", e.name);
    console.log("Error", e.message);
}
```

`error.stack` is not exactly what you want, but it will help you.

Answer (score 20):

This will show you the various ways in which you can get the info available:

```
var str = '{"test": 1, }';

try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch(e) {

    console.log("error object:");
    console.log(e);
    console.log();

    console.log("error object toString():");
    console.log("\t" + e.toString());

    console.log();
    console.log("error object attributes: ");
    console.log('\tname: ' + e.name + ' message: ' + e.message + ' at: ' + e.at + ' text: ' + e.text);

    console.log();
    console.log("error object stack: ");
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

The output is:

```
error object:
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token }]

error object toString():
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

error object attributes: 
    name: SyntaxError message: Unexpected token } at: undefined text: undefined

error object stack: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/james/devel/tests/node/test.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

You can take your pick :-)